# How do I test AWS failure modes?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've got application that accesses Amazon Web Services APIs. As the recent outage demonstrated there are various ways that the service can fail. Is there an easy way to simulate AWS failures and error conditions so that I can test my application and make it more reliable?

Comment: Years later I've yet to find an answer for this. It seems like there is not a good way to simulate what happens when AWS _itself_ goes wonky.

Answer (score 0):

[Chaos Monkey](http://techblog.netflix.com/search/label/chaos%20monkey) from NetFlix might be suitable

Comment: "Chaos Monkey is a service which runs in the Amazon Web Services (AWS) that seeks out Auto Scaling Groups (ASGs) and terminates instances (virtual machines) per group" -- Not really what I'm looking for. Chaos Monkey kills instances but assumes that AWS itself is functional and responsive. How would one go about testing simulating what to do when AWS itself has gone crazy?

Comment: Hey @BradDixon - Are you specifically referring to Service Outage exceptions and things of that nature, or from a DevOps standpoint how to make your infrastructure more bulletproof in case of disaster?

Comment: I was really intrigued on how to handle expected errors and faults in AWS itself. Chaos Monkey makes good sense for testing what to do if you application itself faults. What that doesn't do is simulate failures or service degradation in AWS. For example what if SNS started declining API calls to shed load during a failure event? How would you application respond? This could be simulated using shims and failure scenarios... has anyone built such a toolkit yet?